# Get files form dir with glob and check if it is in array then include?

Tags: php

How could I use the php function `glob` to get files from a directory and put them in an array and then include them with `index.php?file=filename` if it exists?

This is what I came up with so far but it doesn't work.

```
$files = glob("files/*.php");
$file = array($files);

if (in_array(..
```

OR is there a smarter way to do this without having to write all pages in the `index.php`?

Comment: Please  clarify the question - it's hard to understand what you're after

Comment: i want pages like index.php?page=signup, index.php?page=login

Comment: have you tried to run code that was posted here? it might help you to decide what you actually wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right you can use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array_intersect):

```
$files = glob("files/*.php");
$allowedFiles = array('1.php', '2.php', '3.php')

$matchedFiles = array_intersect($files, $allowedFiles);

foreach ($matchedFiles as $file)
{
    // do something with 'index.php?file=' . $file
}
```

Not sure what you mean by "include them with ..."

Answer (score 0):

`glob` returns an array, so you don't need to do anything else with it. example in docs shows something similar to the following:

```
foreach (glob("files/*.php") as $filename) {
    echo "index.php?file=".basename($filename, ".php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don'know if i've understood but if you want to put all files in an array and send it to the index.php page this is the way to do it:

```
$files = glob("files/*.php");
$group=array();
foreach($files as $file) $group[]="file[]=$file";
$path="index.php".(count($group) ? "?".implode("&",$group) : "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = glob("files/*.php");
foreach($files as $file) $group[]="index.php?page=$file";
```

Now in the $group array you have the pages paths